# Scrape with Splash Requests returns empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape a cooking site, but in vain. I have done it with selenium but is a bit slow. So I am trying with scrapy, but it returns always empty strings
I have also modified the settings.py from according to steps 1-5 from https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class CookingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cooking'
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://akispetretzikis.com/en/recipe/6641/patates-twn-15-wrwn'
        headers = {
            ":authority": "akispetretzikis.com",
            "accept": "image / avif, image / webp, image / apng, image / svg + xml, image / *, * / *;q = 0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,el-GR;q=0.8,el;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6",
            "referer": "https://akispetretzikis.com/_next/static/css/6d2cea28911cae6f.css",
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Linux",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "image",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "no-cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same - origin",
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, headers=headers,  args={"wait": 10},callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        yield {
            "name": response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center"]/text()').extract()
        }
```

thank you

Comment: Selenium is pretty slow i agree, but I do like it a lot. Not used scrapy before but if you don't have much luck. Beautiful soup 4 is my next goto, it's worth a look.

Comment: u have any solution expect to go to selenium? Something is probably wrong with my code but I dont know what, I alter my useragent I am using splash but nothing

Comment: Let me see if I can knock something up, give me a bit of time.

Comment: question, did you run the docker container?

Comment: yes I did run the docker, the code is working on u?

Comment: open the browser and test it there first.  http://0.0.0.0:8050/   you can render a page.

Comment: Also I see an issue as the content doesn't load, its just a splash screen. I've also tired it just using the requests library with no luck as its probably a react app and request doesn't handle JS just pulls the HTML from the server.

Comment: So selenium is the answer, because I am noob on this, could u explain a or if u have a link which desribes why splash cannot load the page?